# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getAggregations()

Tags: magento2.3.4

I'm getting following error when I try to open the search result page.

I've tried to debug this error a lot but not getting any clue.

I've elasticsearch enabled & configured 6.5.4

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getAggregations() on null in 
 vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/ResourceModel/Fulltext/Collection.php:645
 Stack trace:
 #0 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\\CatalogSearch\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Fulltext\\Collection->getFacetedData('category')
 #1 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\\CatalogSearch\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Fulltext\\Collection\\Interceptor->___callParent('getFacetedData', Array)
 #2 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\\CatalogSearch\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Fulltext\\Collection\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}('category')
 #3 generated/code/Magento/CatalogSearch/Model/ResourceModel/Fulltext/Collection/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\\CatalogSearch\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Fulltext\\Collection\\Interceptor- in vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/Model/ResourceModel/Fulltext/Collection.php on line 645
```

Comment: Have you any custom table?

Comment: @DhadukMitesh no

Comment: how u fix errors any suggestions? i am getting same error

Comment: @NavinBhudiya Remove vendor folder and reinstall via composer.

Comment: okay i will try and let you know..